# укоротить код возможно?

Tags: python

можно ли эту часть кода как то "оптимизировать"?

```
def on_press_true_button(self):
        global numbering_text_t1,numbering_text_t2,numbering_text_t3,numbering_text_t4,numbering_text_t5,numbering_text_t6,numbering_text_t7,Item_id
        #print(Item_id)
        if Item_id == "Стандарт +14":
            if numbering_text_t2 < limit_t2 -1:
              numbering_text_t2 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t2[numbering_text_t2])
            else:
              numbering_text_t2= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t2[numbering_text_t2])

        elif Item_id == "Подростки +16":
            if numbering_text_t3 < limit_t3 -1:
              numbering_text_t3 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t3[numbering_text_t3])
            else:
              numbering_text_t3= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t3[numbering_text_t3])

        elif Item_id == "Экстрим +18":
            if numbering_text_t4 < limit_t4 -1:
              numbering_text_t4 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t4[numbering_text_t4])
            else:
              numbering_text_t4= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t4[numbering_text_t4])

        elif Item_id == "Безумие +21":
            if numbering_text_t5 < limit_t5 -1:
              numbering_text_t5 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t5[numbering_text_t5])
            else:
              numbering_text_t5= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t5[numbering_text_t5])

        else:
            if numbering_text_t1 < limit_t1 -1:
              numbering_text_t1 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t1[numbering_text_t1])
            else:
              numbering_text_t1= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_t1[numbering_text_t1])

        
    def on_press_action_button(self):
        global numbering_text_y1,numbering_text_y2,numbering_text_y3,numbering_text_y4,numbering_text_y5,numbering_text_y6,numbering_text_y7

        if Item_id == "Стандарт +14":
            if numbering_text_y2 < limit_y2 -1:
              numbering_text_y2 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y2[numbering_text_y2])
            else:
              numbering_text_y2= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y2[numbering_text_y2])

        elif Item_id == "Подростки +16":
            if numbering_text_y3 < limit_y3 -1:
              numbering_text_y3 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y3[numbering_text_y3])
            else:
              numbering_text_y3= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y3[numbering_text_y3])

        elif Item_id == "Экстрим +18":
            if numbering_text_y4 < limit_y4 -1:
              numbering_text_y4 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y4[numbering_text_y4])
            else:
              numbering_text_y4= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y4[numbering_text_y4])

        elif Item_id == "Безумие +21":
            if numbering_text_y5 < limit_y5 -1:
              numbering_text_y5 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y5[numbering_text_y5])
            else:
              numbering_text_y5= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y4[numbering_text_y5])
      
        else:
            if numbering_text_y1 < limit_y1 -1:
              numbering_text_y1 += 1
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y1[numbering_text_y1])
            else:
              numbering_text_y1= 0
              self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_y2[numbering_text_y1])
```

Comment: можно всё это просчитать на старте и выдавать {key: cycle()}

Comment: @eri можите продемонстрировать код ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Замечания

Налицо изначально неправильный дизайн приложения, из-за чего простой, казалось бы, рефакторинг, превращается в сложную задачу. Притом, используемые для рефакторинга способы, тоже неоптимальны и непрозрачны, что повлечёт за собой проблемы в будущем.

**Основные проблемы**

- чрезмерное использование глобальных переменных. Гуглите "Почему глобальные переменные зло".
- использование переменных вида `variable_1`, `variable_2`, `variable_3`, наводит на мысль, что их можно было бы заменить одной переменной типа `sequence`, например словарём:

  вместо 7 переменных

  ```
   numbering_text_y1 = "text" 
   numbering_text_y2 = "text"
   numbering_text_y3 = "text"
   numbering_text_y4 = "text"
   numbering_text_y5 = "text"
   numbering_text_y6 = "text"
   numbering_text_y7 = "text"
  ```

  можно использовать одну

  ```
   dct = {
       "numbering_text_y1" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y2" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y3" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y4" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y5" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y6" : "text",
       "numbering_text_y7" : "text"
   }
  ```

  Кроме снижения количества переменных, это решает проблему с передачей переменной в другую функцию и её изменение там. В случае же с глобальными переменными, в другую функцию приходится передавать имя этой переменной в виде строки и использовать там `globals()` (что я и сделал в своём решении), ведь в Python нельзя передавать переменную по ссылке.
- Как вы сами заметили, много `if`-ов и дублирования, что является следствием (и показателем) плохого дизайна - повторное использование кода (вынесение повторяющихся действий в отдельную функцию) затруднено из-за того, что глобальные переменные являются объектами неизменяемого типа - `int`, `str`. Мы не можем передать `numbering_text_y1` в другую функцию и там изменить его значение. Чтобы это сделать, надо чтобы `numbering_text_y1` был объектом изменяемого типа - либо встроенного (`list`, `dict`, ...), либо самодельного, созданного с помощью `class`.

Трудно сказать, как стоило бы спроектировать ваше приложение, не видя всего кода и не зная его логики. Рекомендую почитать что-нибудь по проектированию и паттернам, мне нравится ***"Фримен Эр., Фримен Эл., Сьерра К., Бейтс Б. Паттерны проектирования"***. Несмотря на то, что там в примерах используется **Java**, они легко переводятся на **Python**. Основные же принципы **ООП** объяснены хорошо.

#### Рефакторинг

Если нет возможности или желания переделывать всё приложение, а сократить дублирование хочется, то можно сделать так (не тестировал):

```
def numbering_text(self, numbering_text_n, limit_n, text_n):
    number = globals()[numbering_text_n]
    number = (number + 1) if (number < limit_n - 1) else 0   

    self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text_n[number])
    globals()[numbering_text_n] = number

def on_press_true_button(self):
    global Item_id

    if Item_id == "Стандарт +14":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_t2", limit_t2, text_t2)
    elif Item_id == "Подростки +16":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_t3", limit_t3, text_t3)
    elif Item_id == "Экстрим +18":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_t4", limit_t4, text_t4)
    elif Item_id == "Безумие +21":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_t5", limit_t5, text_t5)
    else:
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_t1", limit_t1, text_t1)

def on_press_action_button(self):
    global Item_id

    if Item_id == "Стандарт +14":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_y2", limit_y2, text_y2)
    elif Item_id == "Подростки +16":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_y3", limit_y3, text_y3)
    elif Item_id == "Экстрим +18":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_y4", limit_y4, text_y4)
    elif Item_id == "Безумие +21":
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_y5", limit_y5, text_y5)
    else:
        self.numbering_text("numbering_text_y1", limit_y1, text_y1)
```

Comment: `from itertools import cycle`, text[number] можно заменить на. Text=cycle(text) ; next(text)

Answer (score 0):

Версию от @MiniMax можно сократить до следующего вида:

```py
def _numbering_text(self, letter):
    global Item_id

    postfix = "1"
    if Item_id == "Стандарт +14":
        postfix = "2"
    elif Item_id == "Подростки +16":
        postfix = "3"
    elif Item_id == "Экстрим +18":
        postfix = "4"
    elif Item_id == "Безумие +21":
        postfix = "5"
    
    postfix = letter + postfix
    numbering_text = "numbering_text_"+postfix
    limit_n = "limit_"+postfix
    text_n = "text_"+postfix
    
    number = globals()[numbering_text]
    limit = globals()[limit_n]
    text = globals()[text_n]
    
    number = (number + 1) if (number < limit - 1) else 0
    
    self.screen.ids.scroll_text.text = str(text[number])
    globals()[numbering_text] = number

def on_press_true_button(self):
    self._numbering_text("t")

def on_press_action_button(self):
    self._numbering_text("y")
```